# How do I cleanly remove rubinius?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rubinius

I used http://railsinstaller.org/ to install a bunch of packages. Then I created a rails app by calling `rails new myApp` and then `rails server`but unfortunately I got this error: [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/3951897)

So I think I would just rather remove rubinius or do some sort of clean install of ruby and all it's dependencies but that might be an issue because I might accidentally delete some files and not remember what they were.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby installer installs RVM for you, which then installs and manages each Ruby for you, so to remove it, at a command line, use:

```
rvm remove rbx-1.10.2
```

Further instructions can be found on the RVM site:

https://rvm.io/rubies/removing/

To add a new Rubinius:

```
rvm install rbx
```

See https://rvm.io/rubies/installing/ for more.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still getting some dependency errors but I think that has to do with the fact that the different versions of ruby has different versions of rails? It's sandboxed or something. Sorry I'm new to this. I think im just going to delete everything as per instructions on the rvm site. Then install using www.railsinsaller.org

Comment: Why are you using Rubinius? The standard Ruby is MRI (1.9.3 at time of writing), so you might try installing that, running Rails (v3 at time of writing) and seeing if you still get errors, and if not then track down the problems regarding Rubinius. If you still get dependency errors with MRI then have a look at your OS, and I'd suggest asking the RVM developers, they're very nice and helpful.

Comment: @tp did this work for you? If so, consider marking the answer as correct. Thanks.